# Putting Rails app into production - rake db:schema:load not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to deploy a new Rails app to a Bitnami/Ubuntu/Virtual Server.  I am remote and using the SSH terminal.

I have successfully used Capistrano to cap deploy:update.  My source is going to github and Capistrano is then putting it on the server.

So, I have this directory on the server:

```
/opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/releases/20130306180756
```

The server also has a PostgreSQL stack running. I have created my Postgresql user and empty database.  I believe my next step is to run this command using the SSH console:

```
bitnami@linux:/opt/bitnami/projects/ndeavor/releases/20130306180756$  rake RAILS_ENV=production db:schema:load
```

Question 1 = Is that the correct next step?

When I run that command, I get this:

```
could not connect to server: No such file or directory
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Questions 2 = How can I get Rake to find the PostgreSQL socket?

I could put something like this in the database.yml file:

```
 socket: /var/pgsql_socket
```

But, I don't know what the correct entry should be

Thanks for your help!!

UPDATE1

I also tried having the database.yml file like this:

```
production:
adapter: postgresql
encoding: unicode
database: ndeavor_production
pool: 5
username: (user name)
password: (password)
socket: /var/run/postgresql
```

But, I get the same error:

```
Is the server running locally and accepting
connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Why isn't it at least asking me for Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql" ??

UPDATE2

I found this:

"I have solved my problem by declaring the unix_socket_directory in postgresql.conf file to be /var/run/postgresql.    It does seem for a standard build they should have a common location?

If you build from unmodified PG sources, the default socket location is
indeed /tmp.  However, Debian and related distros feel that this
violates some distro standard or other, so they modify the source code
to make the default location /var/run/postgresql.  So it depends on
whose build you're using."

But, I'm not sure if I should be changing the postgresql.conf file or the Rails database.yml file

UPDATE3

I looked in /var/run/postgresql directory and it's empty.

I can't find where the .s.PGSQL.5432 is located

Comment: Is your PostgreSQL working? Can you connect with it using command line?

Comment: Yes, I can connect via SSH and I've set it up so that I can connect via pgAdmin3 remotely

Comment: try to specify ```host``` and ```port``` options in ```database.yml```

Comment: Would the host be localhost - because it's on the same machine as the Rails code?

Comment: Bob - thanks that worked !!!  If you want to put it as an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Bob noted, specifying host and port can fix the problem.  Since he hasn't explained this in more detail I want to specify.

The default port is 5432, and the default "host" is a path to where it expects the socket. Port is always numeric, but host can be set for any libpq connection *either* to the network host or to the directory containing the socket.  For example, connect using psql with

```
psql -h /tmp -p 5432 -U chris mydb
```

This will connect over the /tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432 socket.  Now Ruby is somewhat different but the pg gem uses libpq so it should behave the same.

If you don't know where the socket is, the obvious next thing to try is the network address, and particularly localhost.